# My computer was not on the approved list. Here is some info

Tags: dual-boot

I have an HP TouchSmart 520-1047C All in one desktop computer.  This is the kind of computer where the computer is attached to the back of the monitor.  This computer has an Intel Core i5 processor running at 2.5 Ghz.  I have upgraded the old time mechanical hard drive to a 1 TB Samsung solid state drive.  The computer has 6 GBs of RAM in it, and I am installing the max it will take, which is 8 GBs.  I am running Windows 10 Home on it now. I wish to dual boot to Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.04.2.

I searched the hardware approved list, and no version of any HP TouchSmart computers are listed.

What should I do?  I would like to burn a flash drive with the installer and then run Ubuntu from the flash drive to get an idea of this OS. If I run it from the flash drive, before actually installing it on my hard drive, can I then tell if it is going to work or not?

Any suggestions on what I might do to increase my chances of success of this install on hardware not yet tested?

Many thanks!

mraroid in Oregon USA

Comment: Boot from the USB installer and you can run it in Live mode that should allow you to test if it is compatible or not.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu

Comment: Many computers are not on the list, but they run fine. The litmus test is booting from the Ubuntu live installation USB (that you will create) and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. When you try it, make sure sound, video, Internet etc work. Once you are happy, install Ubuntu.